# Rails 3 Rake Clone Database for Testing Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

Is there a rake command in Rails 3 to clone my development database data? I noticed `rake db:test:prepare` and `rake db:test:clone` are mentioned throughout various blogs, but running them seems to do nothing. Furthermore, `rake -T` shows no `db:test` cases. I've resorted to loading a sql dump for now, but it would be great if I could just clone my existing development data for up-to-date testing.

**EDIT --**
I desire to test on a database since I am dealing with legacy data that I run through model filters when accessed. Factories won't work for me in this context, since data passed through `create` is defined as a different schema than that of the legacy data.

Comment: I have also seemingly lost `rake db:test:clone` -- did you ever figure out how to get it back?

Comment: I believe they removed it in Rails 3.

Comment: Yeah, but `rake db:test:prepare` is still there. It's just hidden (i.e. doesn't have a description so it doesn't show when you do `rake -Tdb`).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer on this one?

Comment: Nevermind.  It's `rake db:test:prepare`.  You should give Aaron Gibralter credit when you get a chance. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`rake db:test:prepare` is still there even though it doesn't show up in `rake -Tdb`. I guess the Rails team decided to de-clutter the `rake -T` output?

Comment: rake db:test:prepare doesn't clone the database. Isn't the OP wanting to clone the database, including data?

Comment: @Jamsi yes, but the OP also asked what happened to the rake tasks that used to be listed when you ran `rake -Tdb`. It turns out that they still exist, but are just not listed because they no longer have `desc`s.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you not clone your development database but rather rely on factories to give you predictable data you can craft for your exact test cases. Sooner or later, relying on having reliable test data in a database you can access will break your tests. It will also break the tests of anyone else who works on the project. And changes/additions to the data will not propagate to other developers as would your carefully constructed factories.

Look over Machinist, FixJour, FactoryGirl and the lot. They really solve the test data problem well and you check them into version control so the rest of your team has access to them.

Comment: I am running FactoryGirl on most of my tests, however, I am dealing with legacy data in my database that runs through filters when accessed. Thus, my real desire is to make sure my legacy conversion filters in my model are tested. As far as I have looked into factories, I have to pass everything through `create`, which creates a newer data standard than what I have in my existing database.

Comment: Can you clarify this? Is the database schema not the same as the Rails schema or are there data currently stored that would not pass validation? In short, what I'm wondering is how you are reading this data in.

Comment: This answer does not deserve downvoting. Even in the case the OP has made the correct answer is still *DO NOT CLONE YOUR DEVELOPMENT DATABASE*. This behavior is not repeatable and produces fragile tests. Instead, a repeatable/maintainable option is to execute SQL scripts to populate the database with legacy data.

Comment: OP mentions he needs to do stuff on the "production" db. This is not a regular rails app, and does not deserve to be "shoehorned" into the default "best practice". DHH's spirit approves of this comment.